# Core data predicate to fetch data based on relation giving error as Unable to parse the format string

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an entity called Files with attributes name, id etc. with a toMany relation with other entity called Category having catId.

I am trying to get data which matches Files.catId within an array of ids.

I am writing a predicate as

```
var idArray: [Int] = [410, 436, 435]
    let catIdPredicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "fileCategory.catId IN %@", idArray)
```

which is giving me error as
**Unable to parse the format string "'fileCategory.categoryId' IN (
    410,
    436,
    435
)**

Can anybody tell me how do I write a predicate for the same?

Comment: Why don't you try `NSPredicate(format: "fileCategory.catId IN %@", categoryArray)` where _categoryArray_ will be [410, 436, 435]

Comment: I have tried that. Here I have written hardcoded values for better understanding. Will update my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: try `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY fileCategory.catId in %@", categoryArray)`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your updated code compiles and runs without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ANY` in predicate like this:

```
let idArray: [Int] = [410, 436, 435]
let catIdPredicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "ANY(fileCategory.catId) IN %@", idArray)
```